# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram

I'm using this structure for Instagram:

```
<?php
        // Supply a user id and an access token
        $userid = "--user--";
        $accessToken = "--token--";

        // Gets our data
        function fetchData($url){
             $ch = curl_init();
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
             $result = curl_exec($ch);
             curl_close($ch); 
             return $result;
        }

        // Pulls and parses data.
        $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/--user--/media/recent/?access_token=--token--");
        $result = json_decode($result);
    ?>


    <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

But this print:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mysite/index.php on line 40

40.line:

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
```

Whats wrong in this structure?

This structure is http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

Comment: Use `var_dump($result->data)` before the foreach structure to learn more about $result->data being an invalid argument for it.

Comment: Most likely youre JSON failed to decode and its returning `false`. Can you put the text value of `$result` in your post? Have you run the text value of `$result` through something like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the structure, it's likely that `$result->data` contains invalid data (i.e. is not an array, or is empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just to check - in your code, you have `$userid = "--user--"` and `$accessToken = "--token--"`, then in the URL, you have `--user--` and `--token--` again - you are replacing them with `$userid` and `$accessToken`? If not, the issue could simply be that Instagram is returning an error, which in turn caused your code to fail.

If you have taken the above in to account and are still getting nothing, then print the value of `$result->data` before the loop (`var_dump($result->data)`) and see what your variable contains.

If the above shows nothing, then try `var_dump($result)` - It is possible that the `json_decode()` has failed and will show `false`.

If `$result->data` is an Array, and it is just that you have no data (I'm not sure what Instagram would retrun if there were no results), add a check to see if the Array is empty before the `foreach()` loop.

```
<!-- This will output the contents of '$result->data' - let us know what it is -->
<?php var_dump($result->data)`) ?>

<?php if(!empty($result->data)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /home/mysite/index.php on line 45

Comment: So the problem is not with your code, it is with the value that is being returned by `fetchData()`. Just before the `if()` loop in the code above, add `var_dump($result->data);` - This will tell you what `$result->data contains, which I suspect will be nothing.

Comment: @DavidGard sorry, i don't understand you. Please, edit my code?

Comment: Have made a edit to my code to show you where to put the `var_dump()`.

Comment: Ok, so that is saying that it doesn't exist. On that line, replace `$result->data` with just `$result` and see what you get.

Comment: object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["error_type"]=> string(25) "OAuthAccessTokenException" ["code"]=> int(400) ["error_message"]=> string(39) "The "access_token" provided is invalid." } } I updated my access token but not same problem.

Comment: So it is a problem with the URL that you are parsing then, as opposed to your code. In my answer abaove, did you see the bit about the `$accseeToken` and `$userid` variables? Are you definatly including them in the URL that your are parsing to the Instagram API?

Comment: Yes, definatly included my API info.

Comment: In that case, I have to declare myslef out, as I do not use the Instagram API. Would you consider at least giving me an up-vote though, as I have help you ascertain where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
        // Supply a user id and an access token
        $userid = "*****";
        $accessToken = "*********";

        // Gets our data
        function fetchData($url){
             $ch = curl_init();
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
             $result = curl_exec($ch);
             curl_close($ch); 
             return $result;
        }

        // Pulls and parses data.
        $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$userid/media/recent/?access_token=$accessToken");
        $result = json_decode($result);
    ?>

<?php if(!empty($result->data)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

tried this on an on line compiler it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This is wrong syntax
Replace it with:

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post){ ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this would help fix the issue?

Comment: See carefully the code I posted last. The problem is at the foreach syntax.